# Solutions for deploying enterprise mobile applications using react native

Tags: react-native, enterprise

I'm looking for solutions for deploying an exclusively internal mobile application for a business using react native. I need to keep it out of the App and Play stores.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks peeps..

Answer (score 0):

**iOS**

Apple's supported way:

- Enroll your Apple Developer Organization in the [Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/how-it-works/). This will allow you to build and distribute within a large business.

Unsupported way:

- Upload the app normally to TestFlight and invite users via [Internal or External testing](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/). Even if you choose to go this route, builds expire after a number of days, so new builds will have to be distributed/updated during that timeframe.

**Android**

- Generate a Signed Release APK and distribute it how ever you'd like. Users will download it to their phones and install it directly
- Upload to Google Play Developer Console and set the uploaded APKs in the "Beta" track. From there you have to provide emails to invite, then they can install directly from the Google Play Store and receive updates (Only invited users will see).

Comment: Are you aware of HockeyApp? If so what are your thoughts?

Comment: I've never used HockeyApp personally, but it's definitely a viable option. I would make sure there is no extra step of adding user emails or expiring builds. From looking at their homepage, they market it with similar functionality as the Apple app store.